# Action Bar, OutlookBar, Navigation bar with SDK 8

Tags: android, navigation, outlook

I would like to get an action bar (navigation or outlook bar) which contains e.g. 6 Icons with text. If I click on an Icon, I would like to replace the content area of the outer control (nesting the 6 buttons) by an inner control in addition to a small back menu on top of it. The back button could also indicate the location where we are. So it is close to the outlook bar used within microsoft office.

I am using android:minSdkVersion="8". So I did not take a closer look to the android action bar. I am currently using the tab control. However, the tab control is not really what I want. Or can this be adjusted to provide my described functionality? I create controls at runtime, so I can tweek it, if someone knows how to get it close to what I am searching for. As alternative I would appreciate a library, with such a control.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Support Library, revision 18](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) extend support of ActionBar down to API v7. [There](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) are good instructions how you can import it (v7 appcompat) to your project.